# Save python results to file

Tags: python, csv, file

I have some python code that returns the results of a url, and I am not sure how to get this to output to a txt or csv file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import requests

url = "https://website.com/completed?startDate=2021-01-01&endDate=2021-01-02"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'Cookie': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Open a file and write the contents.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
with open("my_file.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(response.text)
```

Look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) to learn more about writing files in Python.

Comment: @SDavis no problem! If you want you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the vote tracker. Also sorry about all the downvotes... stackoverflow can be a little hostile sometimes!